# action controller asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate, razor

I did this art of code and i have a problem

- the query Update doesn't work and i don't know why
- i am redirected always to the age index
  File Edit.cshtml

> ```
>  @model DATA2.User
>      @{ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
>          Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_General.cshtml";
>      }
>      @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Administration"))
>      {
>      <table>
>      <tr>
>          <td><label    >                             </label></td>
>                  <td>
>                     <label  title= "Name "  style="font-weight:bold" >             Name                 </label>
>                     </td>
>                     <td><label  title= "Email "  style="font-weight:bold" >             Email                
>  </label></td>
>                      <td><label  title= "Password " style="font-weight:bold"  >             Password                
>  </label></td>
>                      <td><label  title= "Phone"  style="font-weight:bold" >             Phone                
>  </label></td>
>                    </tr>
>                   <tr >
>                           <td><label  style="font-weight:bold"  >            Recent                 </label></td>
>                          <td><label    >             @Model.ContactName                 </label></td>
>                     <td><label    >             @Model.ContactEmail                 </label></td>
>                      <td><label    >             @Model.Password                 </label></td>
>                      <td><label    >             @Model.ContactPhone                 </label></td>
>                         </tr>
>                 <tr>
>                 <td><label   style="font-weight:bold" >            New                 </label></td>  
>                     <td><input id="nom" name= "Pseudo" style="width: 156px"/></td>     
>                     <td><input id="mail" name= "Pseudo" style="width: 156px"/></td>      
>                      <td><input id="mot" name= "Pseudo" style="width: 156px"/></td>  
>                      <td><input id="phone" name= "Pseudo" style="width: 156px"/></td>
>                 </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                   <td><label  id="id"  style="visibility:hidden" >@Model.Identification</label></td>
>                   <td><input type="submit" value="Modify"     style="width: 156px; position:relative" /></td>
>                    </tr>
>       </table>
>
> }
> ```

the action Save :

```
public ActionResult Save(string id, string nom, string mail, string phone, string mot)
        {

          if(c.UpdateUser(id, (c.GetPassword().Count + 1).ToString(), mot, "", nom, phone, mail))   return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Administration");
          else return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administration"); 

        }
```

the method UpdateUser

```
public bool UpdateUser(string identification, string acc, string mot, string notify, string nom, string phone, string mail)
       {
          if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(identification)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(acc)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nom)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mail)) && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(mot)) && Email_Exist(mail) == -1)
               {
                   using (NHibernate.ISession nhSession = User.OpenSession())
                   {
                       nhSession.Transaction.Begin();
                       User u = new User() { Account = acc, Identification = identification, ContactEmail = mail, ContactName = nom, ContactPhone = phone, NotifyEmail = notify, Password = mot };
                       nhSession.Update(u);
                       nhSession.Transaction.Commit();
                       nhSession.Close();
                       return true;
                   }
               }
               return false;}
```

always i am redirected to the page index why?

Comment: the error is  "NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [DATA2.User#DATA2.User]"

Comment: `!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(mot)` should be `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mot)`

Comment: All the HTML seems irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would first load the object from NHibernate, then change the properties in that instance. You are also some making some useless calls to NHibernate:

```
using (NHibernate.ISession nhSession = User.OpenSession())
using (var trans = nhSession.BeginTransaction())
{
    User u = nhSession.Get<User>(id);

    // Now update non-identifier fields as you wish.

    // Since the instance is already known by NH, the following
    // is enough (with default NH settings) to persist the changes.
    trans.Commit();
}

return true;
```

There is no need to call Close() on the session, since that is taken care of by the using-statement. Also, it looks extremely strange to call OpenSession() on the User class - it doesn't belong in you data representing classes.